# Windows Forms - Report Designer

Tags: winforms, reporting

Are there solutions available for allowing users to define report layouts within a WinForms app?  We are playing with xml, xslt, and Word have some ok results, but are wondering if there are better options.

We would like to:

1. Set margins, padding, positioning of elements
2. Declare column based or continuous report elements
3. Does not need to do typesetting

Answer (score 1):

Our Data Dynamics Reports product includes a End User Designer Control for Windows Forms that you can drag & Drop onto a Windows Forms and provide a full-featured report designer to your end users. Visit the [Data Dynamics Reports Product Page](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT/), select the Features tab and look at the heading "Designer control" near the bottom of the features page.

Although not the main focus of [this screencast](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT/ScreencastViewer.aspx?ID=DSXML), it does show a bit about the End User Designer control.

Finally, if you download the free evaluation (click Download the [main product page](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT/)) select Sample Gallery from the Start Menu (under Data Dynamics). The Sample Gallery form that pops up is a detailed demonstration of using our End User Designer control.

```
Scott Willeke
Data Dynamics / GrapeCity
```

Answer (score -3):

use visual studio to create the report. Assuming that you're using a reportviewer component, you can add report definition files to your project (.rdlc) and the IDE provides a GUI for you to edit the reports.

Comment: the goal is user defined, not developer designer report layouts